# Did Java get a new feature to supplant `ThreadLocalRandom`?

Tags: java, random, thread-safety

I vaguely recall reading some mentions that [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) has been supplanted in modern Java by some new random number generators.

Did Java add a new feature for housing a random number generator per thread?

Perhaps I am thinking of [*JEP 356: Enhanced Pseudo-Random Number Generators*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356), explained well in this article, [*Random Number Generators in Java 17*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-17-random-number-generators) by Daniel Strmecki on Baeldung.com. But I do not see any discussion on those pages regarding a replacement for `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: Did they perhaps misunderstand [JEP 356](https://openjdk.org/jeps/356)?

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed, I think it was related to new Random Number Generators. But I never saw any detail explanation, only references to `ThreadLocalRandom` being old-school.

Comment: Without seeing the exact statements, we can’t tell what they meant. But you can see any of the new random number generators as a replacement for `ThreadLocalRandom` if it fits your particular use case.